# Error selecting range cells to copy from multiple work books

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

Updated in response to comment from dwirony:

I am trying to create a code that copies information from the same cells in multiple workbooks and combines the information into a single summary workbook.  The code below works as written, however, if I add more cell address to the sourceRange (starting on line 69) the macro still runs but no information is copied into the new summary workbook.

Original Question:

I am trying to select the same specific cells from multiple worksheets within a single folder and combine them into a master spreadsheet.  The code works up to a certain number of cells, but if I try to include any more, the macro returns a blank workbook (except for the column headings I've assigned).  Cells that work initially will won't work if there are too many selected cells.  i.e., in the code shown below, cell J2 is the first and the last cell called and the program runs.  If I add J2 again, (range ends ...J2, J2")or any other cell, it appears that I've hit a limit somewhere and I get a blank workbook.

I have zero previous experience with VBA and macros, and everything I've put together comes from a variety of internet and internal sources.  Maybe the multiple sources are the source of the error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim a As Range, c As Range
    Dim x As Long

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "C:\Users\amiller\OneDrive - CoorsTek\temp"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("J2, C2, D7, F7, K7, G10, J10, G11, J11, G12, J12, G14, J14, G15, J15, G16, J16, G17, J17, J21," _
                    & "J2, D24, E24, G24, I24, J24, O24, P24, Q24, R24, S24, D25, E25, G25, I25, J25, O25, P25, Q25, R25, S25," _
                    & "D26, E26, G26, I26, J26, O26, P26, Q26, R26, S26, D27, J2")

                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else

                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum + 1)

                        x = 0
                        For Each a In sourceRange.Areas
                            For Each c In a.Cells
                                x = x + 1
                                destrange.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = c.Value
                            Next c
                        Next a

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but that definitely doesn't look right to me... I think you're trying to assign too many things to the `sourceRange`. You need to edit your post with more information: What does your code do? What change are you trying to make? What **specific error** are you getting, and on what line? With all the code you've provided, it's hard for anyone to address your issue clearly.

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem I'm having.  I am trying to pull a large number of cells from multiple workbooks into a single one by selecting those sells within "sourceRange" and copying them into "destrange" in the master file.  Is there a better way to do this?